# Exposed Filters in more better way

Tags: search, views

i have a view  with lot of exposed fields for searching  ... (50 +)
[image: Ugly view]

i am looking for some thing like this.
[image: nice one]

with  "add more " button you can add only the fields you want to search in ..
possible ?

thanks

Comment: You can do it by custom code.

Comment: Yes i guess that would be the last option .

Comment: did the dirty trick with jQuery , make a `<select id='hider_s'>` list in the views TPL , and print all the fields names in it and `<option value="$theFieldID">`. Hide all the exposed fields with css , and add below jQuery to select list . `jQuery('#hider_s').on('change', function() {
$selectedval=this.value;

jQuery("#"+$selectedval).css("display","inline");
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery , make a `<select id='hider_s'>` list in the views TPL , and print all the fields names in it and `<option value="$theFieldID">`. Hide all the exposed fields with css , and add below jQuery to select list . `jQuery('#hider_s').on('change', function() { $selectedval=this.value; jQuery("#"+$selectedval).css("display","inline"); });`

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help - [Views Dependent Filter](https://drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters).

> Allows the presence of exposed filters on a view to be controlled by
>   values in another exposed filter. Dependent filters are hidden when
>   not relevant, and their values are not considered when the exposed
>   form is submitted.

Comment: yes thats good , what it does that it just shows and hides the relevant fields based on a value . e.g if the magic word to show "lastname field" is "showMeLastName" then it will show the "last name" field , but as soon as u type "showMeMotherName" it will hide the last name .. i meant just one field will be shown ...

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't really solve your problem, [Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) has a "Secondary exposed form" option. That allows you to select some number of filters and put them into a collapsible fieldset. So, you could have your primary filter options shown with (eg: English search options) with the Arabic options held in the fieldset.

Like I said, not exactly what you were asking for, but to do what you've shown would take custom coding -- probably easiest to do in the theme layer, or you could write a custom exposed form plugin.

Comment: yes , better exposed filter can be an option , i will give it a shot :) , thanks